# How can I export data to an Excel file with APP WinUI3?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2022, windows-store, winui-3

I don't know how to export data from a ListView to Excel using a Winui3 APP tecnology.
With WPF I used "Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
but in WinUI3 technology it doesn't work

```
Excel._Workbook MyExBook;
Excel.Workbooks MyExBooks;
Excel._Worksheet MyExSheet;
Excel.Sheets MyExSheets;
Excel.Range MyExRange;
ButExcel.IsEnabled = false;

try
{
    MyExApp = new Excel.Application();
    MyExBooks = MyExApp.Workbooks;
    MyExBook = MyExBooks.Add();
    MyExSheets = MyExBook.Worksheets;
    MyExSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyExSheets[1];
}
catch
{
    ButExcel.IsEnabled = true;
    return;
}
```

Comment: https://blog.elmah.io/export-data-to-excel-with-asp-net-core/

Comment: You may add more details about 'don't work'. Just do a quick test, the Office automation works well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use Excel itself to generate `xlsx` files. These files are ZIP packages containing well-defined XML files. There several libraries that can easily generate real Excel files, eg Epplus, ClosedXML, NPOI and many more.

These libraries offer several convenience methods that can load data from collections, DataTables or DataReaders directly. For example, using [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus), you can create an Excel file from a list of Products with :

```
var producs=new List<Product>();
//Load the list somehow

using (var p = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var sheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet");
    var range = sheet.Cells["C1"].LoadFromCollection(products);
   
    p.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"c:\workbooks\myworkbook.xlsx"));
}
```

You can load the data with headers, as a table, using one of the predefined styles too:

```
var tableRange = sheet.Cells["C1"].LoadFromCollection(products, true, TableStyles.Dark1);
// to get access to the created table:
var table = sheet.Tables.GetFromRange(tableRange);
```

[ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Inserting-Data) allows writing similar code :

```
    var wb = new XLWorkbook();
    var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Inserting Data");
    var rangeWithPeople = ws.Cell(7, 6).InsertData(people.AsEnumerable());

    ...
    wb.SaveAs("InsertingData.xlsx");
```

To create a table you need to use `InsertTable` instead of `InsertData`:

```
    var table= ws.Cell(7, 6).InsertTable(people.AsEnumerable(),"MyTable");
```

Both libraries also work with DataTable results

Comment: Thanks, with ClosedXML it works very well.